# using Grafana for a customized dashboard

Tags: influxdb, grafana

Is it possible to use Grafana for showing the InfluxDb's data in a different manner than the dashboard and plugins available? I have already used Grafana for other monitor application but this case is pretty strange.

I have some reading regarding the temperature of a liquid when it passes from one "box" to one other. I have to show the value of the temperature before the entering and even after the leaving of the box.

Unfortunately I need to show this situation graphically, something like this:

```
--> temp_in --> [ROOM 1] --> temp out [...] --> temp_in --> [ROOM 2] --> temp out [...]
```

Is possible to reproduce it in Grafana customizing one dashboard (or plugin) or is it better to choose another strategy?

Answer (score 0):

Grafana is designed to make it easy to create dashboards, you can build whatever dashboard you need.

You can find more info about creating dashboards in the docs:

http://docs.grafana.org/guides/getting_started/

As far as your visualization, I'd recommend experimenting with this plugin, which sounds like it might suit your requirements:

https://grafana.com/plugins/jdbranham-diagram-panel

Comment: Thank you, I am grateful for your help. I will check it!